# default event not stopped in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I am having a cross browser issue.

My code is

```
$("<textarea/>").attr('rows',1).attr('wrap','off').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
       $(this).trigger("dtSaveData");
       event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The function called above is:

```
$row.on("dtSaveData", function() {
            // some function
});
that.$table.find("textarea").first().focus();
```

The text area is focussed, but a Enter press event is triggered along with it.
The textarea has only 1 row.

Comment: I assume the first piece of code is wrapped inside a function, can we see it?

Comment: The code it is wrapped in is                                                                $("<textarea/>").attr('rows',1)
                .attr('wrap','off')
                .keydown(function(event) {});

Comment: Try adding a `return false;` following `event.preventDefault;` Also, edit your question with any additional code please instead of posting it in the comments. I added it for you, please correct my edit though if added incorrectly.

Comment: @François: `return false;` is just a shortcut for `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();`.

Comment: Thanks @FrançoisWahl for editing the code but return false does not work.

Comment: Instead of the `keydown` event, try listening to `keyup` and use `e.which` instead of `e.keyCode`.

Comment: Where do you append the in-memory textarea to the document (You're using "<textarea/>")?

Comment: @Prinzhorn i am appending that to a table.

Comment: @FelixKling: I know that `return false` is both methods, but thought it can't hurt to try to include `event.stopPropagation()` as well as not all code is always given, it was a complete shot in the dark, I know :)

Comment: @FelixKling That would ruin the functionality in chrome as well. I need to capture the event as soon as key is pressed.

Comment: @FelixKling I think the issue is with the order in which the events are handled in the firefox. I read about it, firefox has different event handling.

Comment: Could you put up a fiddle showing the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Your selector `$('<textarea/>')` is not going to work. You just need `$('textarea')`

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(event) {
   $(this).trigger("dtSaveData");
   event.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: `$('<textarea/>')` is not a selector, it will create a new `<textarea>`.

Comment: The problem is not with textarea. It is not a selector. Also it is working fine in Chrome opera and safari. It is only having problem with firefox.